# Citrix receiver 4.11 Windows 10 64 bit repeated download prompt

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, citrix, receiver

I've just downloaded latest Citrix Receiver onto my Windows 10 64 bit system.
Everything works ok with one exception.
Every time I launch the calling browser, whether Chrome, Edge or Firefox, I'm prompted to download latest version of Citrix Receiver.
Does not seem to be an option to avoid this, so have to do and when the download executes it reports latest version already loaded and I can then get onto my remote site.
Any ideas?

Thanks
Perry

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to run Citrix install as admin, so it can write to the registry or where it is that the browser is checking